# CountDistinct in a dataframe from two different table Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, count

I have a problem with the CountDistinct on pyspark. I have two joined table and I wanted to show the number of distinct key values of the two different tables.

```
input_table = spark.read.parquet(path + table_name1)
input_table2 = spark.read.parquet(path + table_name2)

impacted_columns = ctrl \
    .where((F.col("tableName1") == table_name1) & (F.col("tableName2") == table_name2)) \
    .join(key, on=['tableName1', 'tableName2']) \
    .join(table, ctrl["tableName1"] == table['tableName']) \
    .groupby("tableName1", 'tableName2', 'key1', 'key2', "keycolumn") \
    .agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("columnName1", "columnName2")).alias('imp_columns')) \
    .first()

input_table = input_table.select(
    [F.col(c.columnName1).alias("T1_" + c.columnName1) for c in impacted_columns.imp_columns] +
    [F.col(c).alias("T1_" + c) for c in
     list(set().union(impacted_columns.key1.split("-"), impacted_columns.keycolumn.split("-")))]
)

input_table2 = input_table2.select(
    [F.col(c.columnName2).alias("T2_" + c.columnName2) for c in impacted_columns.imp_columns] +
    [F.col(c).alias("T2_" + c) for c in
     list(set().union(impacted_columns.key2.split("-"), impacted_columns.keycolumn.split("-")))]
)

ppp= input_table \
        .join(input_table2, [input_table["T1_" + f] == input_table2["T2_" + s] for (f, s) in
                             zip(impacted_columns.key1.split("-"), impacted_columns.key2.split("-"))],
              "left_anti")
plu= input_table2 \
        .join(input_table, [input_table["T1_" + f] == input_table2["T2_" + s] for (f, s) in
                             zip(impacted_columns.key1.split("-"), impacted_columns.key2.split("-"))],
              "left_anti")
pppc=F.countDistinct(ppp.select(["T1_"+c for c in impacted_columns.key1.split("-")]))
pluc=F.countDistinct(plu.select(["T2_" + c for c in impacted_columns.key2.split("-")]))
```

But it doesn't work, does anybody know what is wrong in my code? (it works till the countDistinct)

```
pppc=F.countDistinct(ppp.select(["T1_"+c for c in impacted_columns.key1.split("-")]))
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[T1_c: string, T1_p: string] of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your get an error because you pass a dataframe to `F.countDistinct`. Each argument to `F.countDistinct` should be a column name.

Try to swap the last two lines with this:

```
ppc = ppp.agg(F.countDistinct(*["T1_"+c for c in impacted_columns.key1.split("-")]))
pluc= plu.agg(F.countDistinct(*["T2_" + c for c in impacted_columns.key2.split("-")]))
```

You can then collect your distinct count at the driver as follows:

```
print(ppc.collect()[0][0])
print(pluc.collect()[0][0])
```

Comment: It gives me the following error:


plu.agg(F.countDistinct(*["T2_"+c for c in impacted_columns.key2.split("-")])).alias('onlykey2')


TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[count(DISTINCT T1_c, T1_p): bigint] of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Comment: What is the output of the lines that I posted(Without the alias, that does not work on a dataframe)?. What is the output of ppuc.show()?

Comment: The output of the ppuc.show() is a df with 1 column: count(DISTINCT T1_Identifier, T1_Username) and 2 as the counting (I am working on a test environment)

Comment: Ok, great, I guess that resolves your question right?

Comment: Yes, I only need a command to select only the number (the last row of the DF)

Comment: There will only be one row in the df and it contains the distinct count. I have updated the answer with an example of how to return the distinct count to the driver.